# Python: How to skip element in map function

Tags: python

Is there a way how to skip element inside map? I use map as part of more complex function.

```
inp = ['a','b','c']
```

I tried some ideas but without success.

```
list(map(lambda x: x,  inp.remove('b')))

list(map(lambda x: x if x != 'b' else pass , inp))
```

Required output:

```
['a', 'c']
```

Thanks to @mglrd89 answer I solved the problem, I first applied filter and after map, below is an example code.

```
fields = {c:list(map(lambda field: field.name, 
            filter(lambda field: field.name != 'val',
            dfu.schema.fields[i].dataType.elementType.fields)))
            for i,c in enumerate(dfu.columns) if c in cols}
```

Comment: Yes, filter then map. First filter the array to get the desirable array elements, then map over them.

Comment: What are you actually using a map for? Do you need a map as such?

Comment: Also, try to avoid the name `input` for a variable since it's the name of a built-in function

Comment: I'm mapping struct fields in spark to dicts , fields = {c:list(map(lambda field: field.name , dfu.schema.fields[i].dataType.elementType.fields)) 
                        for i,c in enumerate(dfu.columns) if c in cols}

Comment: In that case, use `filter` or a comprehension. Maps are slower and generally a bit less pythonic than comprehensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the undesired element by filtering it with `filter`:

```
inp = ['a','b','c']
inp_without_b = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'b', inp))
print(inp_without_b)

# Output: ['a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension.

```
result = [mapper_function(x) for x in input_list if condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is

```
result = [x for x in inp if x != 'b']
```

```
>>> print(result)
['a', 'c']
```